# Excel countif - how to count characters like "*", "?", "<"

Tags: excel, special-characters, countif

If I want to count the actual character "*" or CHAR(42" in a range or within a string, how can this be done and get around doing a wildcard? Using CHAR(42) does not get around this unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with any character then you will need to use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$7="<")*1)
```

Comment: Thank you @scottcraner. The *1 did it. I could not get sumproduct to work before that.

Answer (score 4):

You can preface the asterisks with a ~ and it will count.  For instance:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"=~*")
```

Returned the expected value.

Counting < and > are slightly different.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"=>")
```

and

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"=<")
```

It's important to note that characters that can be used as a wild card must have the tilde ~ preceding it.

Comment: This does work for the `*`  and `?` but does not work for `<` or `>`

Comment: @ScottCraner Made an edit, but your answer is much better.

Comment: No this is better as it is not an array formula.  Just note that those can be used as a wild card must have the tilde `~` preceding.  so you can put the `=` in front of anything and it will count it. `=~*`, `=~?`, `=>`, or `=<`

Comment: I did try =COUNTIF($I$2:$AR$73,"~"&F79) and =COUNTIF($I$2:$AR$73,"="&F79)

The charaters I want counting are in column F. "~"&"F79" worked for "*" but not for normal characters, and "="&F79 resulted in a regular wildcard count.

Comment: Thanks @sous2817. Didn't know about the use of "~".