COUNTIF() function is not counting cells I want
I am doing a small project for fun on excel and I got stumped on a COUNTIF() function. Honestly shocked this happened just based on how simple this code was.
Essentially I made a small stock data analysis tool which takes data of the stock's daily perfromance (In this case SPY). It has about a years worth of data which is divided into sections, all days where there are changes greater than 2% and everyother change in .10% increments is sorted as well (e.g. between 1.90 and 1.80, between 1.80 and 1.70). I believe all instances were appropriately categorized but when I want to count the number of days that are in each category using COUNTIF(), the 2% changes are not accounted for. I thought it might be an issue of the returned figure being a string but I don't think thats the problem... Anyone know what's up?
I saw some posts about apostrophes tainting the code. Is this a possibility?
=IF(J2>2%,"> 2%",IF(J2<-2%,"< -2%",
IF(J2<=-2%+0.001,"-2% to -1.90%",
IF(J2<=-1.9%+0.001,"-1.90% to -1.80%",
IF(J2<=-1.8%+0.001,"-1.80% to -1.70%",
IF(J2<=-1.7%+0.001,"-1.70% to -1.60%",
IF(J2<=-1.6%+0.001,"-1.60% to -1.50%",
IF(J2<=-1.5%+0.001,"-1.50% to -1.40%",
IF(J2<=-1.4%+0.001,"-1.40% to -1.30%",
IF(J2<=-1.3%+0.001,"-1.30% to -1.20%",
IF(J2<=-1.2%+0.001,"-1.20% to -1.10%",
IF(J2<=-1.1%+0.001,"-1.10% to -1.00%",
IF(J2<=-1%+0.001,"-1.00% to -0.90%",
IF(J2<=-0.9%+0.001,"-0.90% to -0.80%",
IF(J2<=-0.8%+0.001,"-0.80% to -0.70%",
IF(J2<=-0.7%+0.001,"-0.70% to -0.60%",
IF(J2<=-0.6%+0.001,"-0.60% to -0.50%",
IF(J2<=-0.5%+0.001,"-0.50% to -0.40%",
IF(J2<=-0.4%+0.001,"-0.40% to -0.30%",
IF(J2<=-0.3%+0.001,"-0.30% to -0.20%",
IF(J2<=-0.2%+0.001,"-0.20% to -0.10%",
IF(J2<=-0.1%+0.001,"-0.10% to 0%",
IF(J2<=0.001,"0% to 0.10%",
IF(J2<=0.1%+0.001,"0.10% to 0.20%",
IF(J2<=0.2%+0.001,"0.20% to 0.30%",
IF(J2<=0.3%+0.001,"0.30% to 0.40%",
IF(J2<=0.4%+0.001,"0.40% to 0.50%",
IF(J2<=0.5%+0.001,"0.50% to 0.60%",
IF(J2<=0.6%+0.001,"0.60% to 0.70%",
IF(J2<=0.7%+0.001,"0.70% to 0.80%",
IF(J2<=0.8%+0.001,"0.80% to 0.90%",
IF(J2<=0.9%+0.001,"0.90% to 1.00%",
IF(J2<=1%+0.001,"1.00% to 1.10%",
IF(J2<=1.1%+0.001,"1.10% to 1.20%",
IF(J2<=1.2%+0.001,"1.20% to 1.30%",
IF(J2<=1.3%+0.001,"1.30% to 1.40%",
IF(J2<=1.4%+0.001,"1.40% to 1.50%",
IF(J2<=1.5%+0.001,"1.50% to 1.60%",
IF(J2<=1.6%+0.001,"1.60% to 1.70%",
IF(J2<=1.7%+0.001,"1.70% to 1.80%",
IF(J2<=1.8%+0.001,"1.80% to 1.90%",
"1.90% to 2%")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))


=COUNTIF(Daytime, P2)

Daytime is the range (each cell in the range is a return value of the 1st function) and P2 = '> 2%
Cells are formated as text.
I was expecting the countif() to return the number of values > 2% in a given range.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727084/16578424 --> you have to kind of escape your condition as otherwise it is not interpreted as text but as a logical condition: =COUNTIF(Daytime,"=" & P2)

Welcome to Stack Exchange. You would be better off defining the bins you want to classify the data into in a column and loading the Data Analysis Toolpack addin() package which has a Histogram function that should pretty much do what you want. Huge long lists of nested IF statements are incredibly prone to errors and so best avoided. () Now hidden in "Options/Add-ins" at bottom left of the screen.
